# Excel Sort By Numbers Macro

Tags: sorting, excel, vba

I use a macro to delete rows which doesnt containing numbers for my report.

This macro find critical path numbers and split them. In a1 column it delete the numbers which doesnt in the list.

This macro works fine. Beside that i want to sort a1 column by critical path number orders.

[In this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7sp7qgxix9okkh9/Report%20Macro.rar) I added what i want and my report file. There is a critical path text at the bottom in report file. When i click Düzenle macro delete rows but not sort by critical path number orders.

Thanks for your helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not like performing complex changes and deleting rows at the same time.  If anything goes wrong, you have to restore the worksheet.  I have introduced a new worksheet "Critical Path" and have copied to it everything required from worksheet "Revit KBK Sonuç" in the desired sequence.

I have described what I am doing and why within the macro.  I hope it is all clear but ask if necessary.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ertert()

  ' I avoid literals within the code if I think those literals may change
  ' over time and/or if I think a name would make the code clearer.
  Const ColLast As Long = 10
  Const ColShtHdrLast As Long = 2
  Const TableHdr1 As String = "Total Pressure Loss Calculations by Sections"

  Dim ColCrnt As Long
  Dim Section() As String
  Dim CriticalPath As String
  Dim InxSect As Long
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim RowDestNext As Long
  Dim RowSrcLast As Long
  Dim RowTableHdr1 As Long
  Dim wshtDest As Worksheet
  Dim wshtSrc As Worksheet

  Set wshtSrc = Worksheets("Revit KBK Sonuç")
  Set wshtDest = Worksheets("Critical Path")

  With wshtDest
    .Cells.EntireRow.Delete
  End With

  ' I only work on the ActiveWorksheet if the user is to select the
  ' target worksheet in this way.  Code is easier to understand if
  ' With statements are used.
  With wshtSrc

    ' Copy column widths
    For ColCrnt = 1 To ColLast
      wshtDest.Columns(ColCrnt).ColumnWidth = .Columns(ColCrnt).ColumnWidth
    Next

    ' I avoid stringing commands together.  The resultant code may be
    ' marginally faster but it takes longer to write and much longer
    ' to decipher when you return to the macro in 12 months.

    ' Extract critial path string and convert to array of Section numbers
    RowSrcLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    CriticalPath = .Cells(RowSrcLast, "A").Value
    ' Extract text before trailing total pressure loss
    CriticalPath = Split(CriticalPath, ";")(0)
    ' Discard introductory text and trim spaces
    CriticalPath = Trim(Split(CriticalPath, ":")(1))
    Section = Split(CriticalPath, "-")

    Set Rng = .Cells.Find(What:=TableHdr1)

    If Rng Is Nothing Then
      Call MsgBox("I am unable to find the row containing """ & _
                                                       TableHdr1 & """", vbOKOnly)
      Exit Sub
    End If

    RowTableHdr1 = Rng.Row

    ' Copy header section of worksheet without buttons
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(RowTableHdr1 - 1, ColShtHdrLast)).Copy _
                                                Destination:=wshtDest.Cells(1, 1)
    ' Copy table header
    .Range(.Cells(RowTableHdr1, 1), .Cells(RowTableHdr1 + 1, ColLast)).Copy _
                                     Destination:=wshtDest.Cells(RowTableHdr1, 1)

    RowDestNext = RowTableHdr1 + 2

    ' Copy rows for each section in critical path to destination worksheet
    For InxSect = 0 To UBound(Section)

      Set Rng = .Columns("A:A").Find(What:=Section(InxSect), LookAt:=xlWhole)

      If Rng Is Nothing Then
        Call MsgBox("I am unable to find the row(s) for Section" & _
                                                   Section(InxSect), vbOKOnly)
      Else
        Set Rng = Rng.MergeArea       ' Expand to include all rows for section
        ' Copy all rows for section
        Rng.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=wshtDest.Cells(RowDestNext, 1)
        ' Step output row number
        RowDestNext = RowDestNext + Rng.Rows.Count
      End If

    Next

    ' Copy critical path row
    .Rows(RowSrcLast).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=wshtDest.Cells(RowDestNext, 1)
    RowDestNext = RowDestNext + 1

  End With

  ' Add border at bottom of output table
  With wshtDest
     With .Range(.Cells(RowDestNext, 1), _
                 .Cells(RowDestNext, ColLast)).Borders(xlEdgeTop)
       .LineStyle = xlContinuous
       .Weight = xlMedium
       .ColorIndex = 16
     End With
  End With

End Sub
```

**New version of macro in response to request**

Because the sections have different numbers of rows, no in situ sort is possible.

Version 1 solved this problem by copying required rows to a different worksheet.  Version 2 solves this problem by copying them to a workarea below the original table but within the same worksheet.  That is, a new table is built beneath the old.

Once the new table is complete, the old table is deleted to move the new table into the correct position.

```
Sub ertert()

  Const ColLast As Long = 10
  Const ColShtHdrLast As Long = 2
  Const TableHdr1 As String = "Total Pressure Loss Calculations by Sections"

  Dim ColCrnt As Long
  Dim Section() As String
  Dim CriticalPath As String
  Dim InxSect As Long
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim RowDestNext As Long
  Dim RowDestStart As Long
  Dim RowSrcLast As Long
  Dim RowTableHdr1 As Long
  Dim wsht As Worksheet

  Set wsht = ActiveSheet

  With wsht

    ' Extract critial path string and convert to array of Section numbers
    RowSrcLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    CriticalPath = .Cells(RowSrcLast, "A").Value
    ' Extract text before trailing total pressure loss
    CriticalPath = Split(CriticalPath, ";")(0)
    ' Discard introductory text and trim spaces
    CriticalPath = Trim(Split(CriticalPath, ":")(1))
    Section = Split(CriticalPath, "-")

    Set Rng = .Cells.Find(What:=TableHdr1)

    If Rng Is Nothing Then
      Call MsgBox("I am unable to find the row containing """ & _
                                                       TableHdr1 & """", vbOKOnly)
      Exit Sub
    End If

    RowTableHdr1 = Rng.Row

    ' Because there is no fixed number of rows per section no in-situ sort is
    ' practical.  Instead copy required rows in required section to destination
    ' area below existing area.

    RowDestStart = RowSrcLast + 2
    RowDestNext = RowDestStart

    ' Copy rows for each section in critical path to destination area
    For InxSect = 0 To UBound(Section)

      Set Rng = .Columns("A:A").Find(What:=Section(InxSect), LookAt:=xlWhole)

      If Rng Is Nothing Then
        Call MsgBox("I am unable to find the row(s) for Section" & _
                                                   Section(InxSect), vbOKOnly)
      Else
        Set Rng = Rng.MergeArea       ' Expand to include all rows for section
        ' Copy all rows for section
        Rng.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=.Cells(RowDestNext, 1)
        ' Step output row number
        RowDestNext = RowDestNext + Rng.Rows.Count
      End If

    Next

    ' Copy critical path row
    .Rows(RowSrcLast).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=.Cells(RowDestNext, 1)
    RowDestNext = RowDestNext + 1


    ' Add border at bottom of output table
    With .Range(.Cells(RowDestNext, 1), _
                 .Cells(RowDestNext, ColLast)).Borders(xlEdgeTop)
      .LineStyle = xlContinuous
      .Weight = xlMedium
      .ColorIndex = 16
    End With

    ' Now have new table on rows RowDestStart to RowDestNext-1.
    ' Delete rows RowTableHdr1+2 to RowDestStart-1 (old table) to
    ' move new table into desired position.

    .Rows(RowTableHdr1 + 2 & ":" & RowDestStart - 1).EntireRow.Delete

  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Tony you are perfect :) THX So much. But it will be better if we can work only one sheet. I dont need critical path because i close this excel file for every report. if anything goes wrong i can copy the report again. Becuse the report is in html mode. I copy it and paste here and click Düzenle. Can you send the code for one sheet please?

Comment: @user3240191. I do not know if you receive a message if an answer is updated. This comment is to ensure you receive a message.  By the way, glad you liked my first solution.  I hope you like the second even better.

Comment: Version 2 works perfectly. Lastly i need something. There is a Temizle button which clear sheet. When i click it it delete texts but i cant unmerge all cells and delete borders.

Here is code : 


    Sub temizle()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    
       ws.UsedRange.ClearContents
    
    Next ws
    End Sub

Comment: `ws.Cells.ClearContents` deletes most stuff but not all.  `ws.Cells.EntireRow.Delete` also deletes most stuff but not all.  Use both and you should delete everything.

Comment: Tony you saved a lot of time. Thanks so much :)